# How to reference parameterized constructor in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, constructor-reference

So I have this definition:

```kotlin
    sealed interface ParseResult<out R> {
        data class Success<R>(val value: R) : ParseResult<R>
        data class Failure(val original: String, val error: Throwable) : ParseResult<Nothing>
    }
```

I want to wrap certain elements in a Success. And I know I can do it like this...

```kotlin
    list.map{ParseResult.Success(it)}
```

But is there a way to use a constructor reference?

```kotlin
   list.map(ParseResult::Success) //this won't compile
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a constructor reference if you add an `import`:

```
import somepackage.ParseResult.Success
```

Or even a typealias:

```
typealias Success<R> = ParseResult.Success<R>
```

Then you can do:

```
list.map(::Success)
```

The idea here is to make `ParseResult.Success` referrable by a simple name.

Not being able to do `ParseResult::Success` does look like a bug to me though. Compare:

```
class Outer {
    class Nested
}
class OuterGeneric<T> {
    class Nested
}

fun main() {
    val x = Outer::Nested // works
    val y = OuterGeneric::Nested // error
}
```